# Get progress of loading scripts via $.getScript in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From using jQuery's $.getScript(), is there a way to have a percentage of how much of the script is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.  Per the documentation, there is only one additional argument to getScript(), a success call back that will fire a script has been fully loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/